# Locking documents in firestore or don't allow two users edit a document at the same time

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, backend

stack: NodeJS, ExpressJS, Firebase DB, VueJs

Question:

How to lock a firebase doc? I want to not allow two users editing a same document on front-end.

Example: Like in front-end if a user fetches a document by some id ant starts editing, editing takes like 10 minutes because there are a lot of inputs, but then a second user comes and tries to edit the same document by id. How to prevent it?

My solution: Create a database collection storing the id of currently edited document. And whenever a user tries to edit an document, there should be a check if the id doesnt exist in the collection and on save button the id should be removed from the collection.

Is my solution is good?

Maybe there are other solutions...

Comment: Normally, that shoudl be handle via [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Comment: But we should not even open a form for a user if the document is being edited by another person. How to prevent that?

Comment: You should implement a system of locking, with a specific field. This is not something we can described in one answer in SO, it can be a complex mechanism, including decisions on how to remove the lock after some time, etc, etc. You will probably find some generic literature on the web on such a mechanism.

Comment: To go along with @frankvanpuffelen answer, the issue with record locking in Firestore is that if a user disconnects, there's no inherent way to know about that event and unlock the document. For example, suppose a user starts an edit which 'locks' it and then force quits the app and never comes back on. That record is forever locked. One option is to leverage the Realtime Database [user persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence) which knows when a user disconnects. So that event could fire a cloud function to 'unlock' the locked document.

Comment: I created a Collection 'TemporaryEdit' which holds id(the document which is being edited) and user(name, surname of a person who is editing). Then if a user comes and want to edit a document, he pass the id of the document, and I check if the id exits in  'TemporaryEdit', if it does then the user can not edit. And after a person finishes editing, I remove the id from 'TemporaryEdit' collection. But if an app shut downs and the id stays in 'TemporaryEdit' that's when I check user. When a user comes to an editing page I first check if the user name and surname doesnt exists in 'TemporaryEdit'.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pessimistic locking built into Firestore, but I'd typically implement this by adding a field to the document that is being locked. Something like `currentEditor` with as its value the UID of the current editor.

To manipulate this field you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to prevent users from overwriting each other's data, and you'll then want to use [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to enforce this.